# Given the matrix C, find a matrix X such that $( X ^T-2I)^{-1}=C$

Tags: matrices

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 \\4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

if somebody can help me to solve this question i tried to solve it but no luck 
while i was trying i thought that if i got C inverse and then add it by I (identity matrix) which makes it transpose = X i do not know if thats right
it will be amazing if someone helped me

thanks

Comment: I am glad that you tried. would you like to include what you have tried and we can try to get you unstuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\quad{( X ^T-2I)^{-1}=C\\
(( X ^T-2I)^{-1})^{-1}=C^{-1}\\( X ^T-2I)=C^{-1}\\X^T-2I=C^{-1}\\X^T=2I+C^{-1}\\X=(2I+C^{-1})^T}$$

Comment: @yara : $C$ is not a square matrix ?

Comment: Very nice, I think $C$ is a square matrix

Comment: the question doesn't make sense then

Comment: can i ask sth how do you understand how to get the x

Comment: i always get stuck when they ask me to find x

Comment: $C_{2\times 2}$ matrix ,so $I_{{2\times 2}}$ matrix too . then $X^T ,X$ must be 2*2 .

Comment: oh got it thanks alt